# CMake configuration CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I would like to set up cmake for a project but I don't know how to do with this architecture :

```
src/
  control/
    file.cpp
    file.h
  factory/
    file.cpp
    file.h
  model/
    file1.cpp
    file1.h
    ...
    file9.cpp
    file9.h
  ui/
    file.cpp
    file.h
  main.cpp
```

I guess it seems easy to people with experience using cmake. I don't know what to write on the different CMakeLists.txt to link the packages. Thanks for help.

Comment: Your structure looks fine. If there are libraries involved I usually put a CMakeLists.txt in each folder so each CMakeLists.txt handles its own folder.

Comment: Do you want to handle each folder as a separate project? It's not necessary, so at the end you'll just having one CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you for your comment. How to write the CMakeLists.txt when there is multiple librabries (e.g. in model) in one folder ?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from having more than 1 add_library() in a CMakeLists.txt. As I said above I don't do it that way but it is a personal preference. There is not a right or wrong way for that.

Comment: @Attis Thank you for your comment. Not especially. I just want it to work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something along these lines:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(test1)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp 
                    src/control/file.h 
                    src/control/file.cpp
                    src/factory/file.h 
                    src/factory/file.cpp
                    # ...
                    )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} OpenSSL::SSL Qt5::Core)
```

This CMakeLists.txt assumes you have at least CMake version 3.12. This example also shows you how to acquire external dependencies like OpenSsl and Qt.